# Boot from SSD with Ubuntu Core 22 on a RPi4

Tags: boot, ssd, raspberrypi, external-hdd, ubuntu-core

Ubuntu Core 22 comes with `Piboot`, which is

> «the one-stage bootloader on Raspberry Pi, offering user experience improvements like booting from external devices and better support for hats»

Ref: [Ubuntu Core 22 Beta is now available](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/ubuntu-core-22-beta-is-now-available/28339) (I couldn't find any details on this in the [official release notes](https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/uc22)).

So I'm wondering if anyone have successfully been able to boot from any external devices, on a raspberry pi 4?

I've tried to boot from an SSD M.2 with a HAT. This setup works perfectly on Ubuntu Server 22.04 (classic and not Core), so I've verified that there nothing wrong with the HAT nor the SSD.

Any guidance or tips is very welcome!

Answer (score -1):

there has been similar issues in the past with ubu server and SSD which were addressed by booting from SD CARD and running system from SDD.
you could also try updating eprom on rpi4 - the new bootloader automatically searches for a bootable device and if none are found it gives you the option to net install an os.
good luck